# 4 related products of same subcategory on wooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to show 4 products at the bottom of the page showing related products. Just products on the same subcategory. To achieve this I've done this changes on related.php

```
$cats_array = array(4);

// Get categories
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );

//Select only the category which doesn't have any children
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
if ( !sizeof( $children ) )
$cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
}

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'no_found_rows' => 1,
'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'tax_query' => array(
 array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => $cats_array
),
)
) );
```

It shows only subcategory related products. The PROBLEM is it sometimes shows 2, sometimes 3... even reloading the same product and it has to be always 4.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.